# Disable automatic screen lock in XFCE in Centos

Tags: gnome, xfce, screen-lock

I have a generic install of Centos 5.8 with XFCE 4.4.  Pretty much all defaults. As is, after a certain amount of idle time the screen locks (goes black, requires a password to continue).

How do I disable the automatic screen lock?

I've searched around and read suggestions to use the settings manager to modify the Power Manager or Screen Saver settings but neither of those settings managers/panels/icons are installed on my desktop.

UPDATE:

It appears `gnome-screensaver` is being started automatically.  Of course I could remove that program from the system, but I'd prefer to understand what's going on and use more ordinary configuration methods to prevent it from automatically starting and at the same time keep the option of switching back to it if needed.

Comment: Do you still need to lock the screen in other situations ?

Comment: @warl0ck Yes, I would like to be able to lock the screen on demand.

Comment: Do you have xscreensaver installed ?

Comment: AFAIK I do not have xscreensaver installed.

Comment: Can you show the output of `ps aux | grep screen`

Comment: @warl0ck, `gnome-screensaver` is running.  I don't know how it got started.

Comment: How are you locking screen anyway, still use gnome-screensaver ?

Comment: Please run this -- **`sudo grep -r gnome-screensaver /`** --  and add it to your question.

Comment: @Gryllida, I let `sudo grep -r gnome-screensaver /` run for 2 hours and other than some errors about reading some devices like `/dev/vsock` it produced no output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ps aux | grep screen` revealed that `gnome-screensaver` was running.

`whereis gnome-screensaver` found it in `/usr/bin` (among other places).

Also in `/usr/bin/` was `gnome-screensaver-preferences`

Solution: run `/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-preferences` and uncheck "Lock screen when screensaver is active". Optionally uncheck "Activate screensaver when computer is idle".

Answer (score 2):

Is gnome-screensaver listed and ticked in *Applications, settings, session and startup, application autostart*? If so, untick it to stop it from starting.

If you don't have the *Session and startup* menu, you can do same thing checking for a gnome-screensaver file in the autostart directory. `$HOME/.config/autostart`

---

Try checking whether there is an active gconf setting that sets gnome-screensaver to start. Per the [xscreensaver manual](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html), a

> `gconftool-2 --type boolean -s /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/screensaver/start_screensaver false`

command stops gnome-screensaver from starting. This means that if you want to see the current setting, you may want to try `

> `gconftool-2 -g /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/screensaver/start_screensaver`

using '-g' instead of '-s' to get instead of set.

Comment: I have a "Sessions and Startup Settings" menu item that brings up a "Sessions and Startup" window, but there is no "application autostart" and the only option that is checked is "Prompt on logout".  The only thing in `$HOME/.config/autostart/` is `xfce4-tips-autostart.desktop` and all it has is `[Desktop Entry]
Hidden=true`

Comment: Added second possible step for solution.

Comment: It had been set to true.  I set it to false.  That did not prevent `gnome-screensaver` from automatically starting.

Answer (score 1):

CentOs:
Applications -> System Tools -> Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock -> Disable it.

If you don't find `Privacy` search for `lock` and you will find the related search check which option says automatic screen lock.

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

```
Install gconf-editor from Add/Remove Software, then go to 
Applications --> System Tools --> Configuration Editor. 
Under Apps --> Panel --> Global look for "disable_lock_screen"
If it is checked, uncheck it.
```

I haven't tried it out, but it sounds promissing.

Also, you could use the command `xfce4-settings-manager` to open this window:

[image]

Here, uncheck the 'Lock screen after' option, or set a different time. Please comment if you succed or not.

Comment: I don't have `xfce4-settings-manager` or `xfce-settings-manager` on my system.  I tried installing `gconf-editor` and checking `disable_lock_screen` but that did not stop the screen from automatically locking, as could be predicted from the description: "If true, the panel will not allow a user to lock their screen, by removing access to the lock screen menu entries."

Comment: @Old Pro - Is there a reason you don't want to install `xfce4-settings-manager`? After all, you are asking about how to change a desktop setting...

Comment: @ire_and_curses I don't mind installing `xfce4-settings-manager` but the OP didn't mention installing it and the screenshot refers to XScreenSaver which also isn't on my system, so it seems unlikely to help.

Answer (score -1):

Press    `Alt + f2` to execute a program

type: `xscreensaver-demo` then hit enter

Then uncheck *"Lock Screen After"* checkbox

Comment: `Alt + F2` did not bring up a command prompt.  I do not have `xscreensaver` or `xscreensaver-demo` on my system. `The command "xscreensaver-demo" failed to run:

Failed to execute child process "xscreensaver-demo" (No such file or directory)`